# Completely changed answer: edit or new answer?

Tags: discussion, editing, answers

In a recent post I changed my answer completely, so I edited it.

But then I thought that, being a "new" answer, it should be a separate one, so I posted a new answer. (I just let the previous one edited).

What would be here the accepted course of action, edit the answer, or post a new  one?

[This is the original answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/584532/338177) (I deleted it) [and the previous version](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/584467/3).

[This is the new answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/584467/338177)

Comment: Do both answers provide a useful solution? Does one complement the other? Are they completely different? Was the original answer wrong?

Comment: @terdon The first one got downvoted without feedback. In a personal note, I have to say that I still don't handle well downvotes. I get insecure and afraid of new downvotes, I tend to delete them. They don't complement each other, they are completely different. The first was wrong? I'm not sure to be honest, maybe it's not *wrong* but just *bad*. It surely could have been better.

Comment: @terdon The first answer also was very similar to other posted, so I took the challenge of posting a new approach, thinking in the likes of "well, my answer is not welcomed, and it's similar to others. Doesn't really add anything useful. Let's try something different."

Comment: Related: [Is it OK to write a new answer after I deleted a downvoted one earlier on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/293023/260388)

Answer (score 5):

If your existing answer had received votes (up- or down-), I would restrict edits to improvements on that answer. If it had not yet received any votes, I say go ahead and change it completely if you want to. I believe that edits within the first few minutes of posting are absorbed into the "initial" version of the posting. After that, there's an edit history.

I don't have a strong opinion on multiple, separate, answers by the same person -- versus one consolidated answer with many variations. I've seen both here. The all-in-one model can showcase your encyclopedic knowledge as well as point out pros & cons between them. Often, a multi-answer post will be community wiki so that others can add their ideas.  The separate-ideas as separate-posts model lets the community vote on ideas that they prefer (for or against).